# Facebook - call canvas application from page

Tags: facebook

I have develop simple facebook canvas application.

http://apps.facebook.com/myappname/

I want to create page and call this application when user click on page.

Any idea how to do this?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's called a "page tab app". Excellent walk thru located here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/